# MySQL duplicate column in sub-query inside join

Tags: mysql

I have the following piece of code:

```
SELECT * FROM uc_redwables AS T1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT dwable , MAX(time) AS time FROM uc_redwables WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5' AND find_in_set(followed, redwabledby) > 0) OR find_in_set('5',`redwabledby`)
GROUP BY dwable
) AS T2
ON T1.dwable = T2.dwable AND T1.time = T2.time
ORDER by T2.time desc LIMIT 20
```

This works as intended.

However when I place it in my larger query:

```
SELECT 
p.`id` as id, 
p.`postinguser` as postinguser,
p.`page` as page,
p.`likedby` as likedby,
p.`redwabled` as redwabled,
case r.`redwabledby`
when (SELECT `followed` FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5') then r.`time`
when '5' then r.`time`
else p.`time`
end as date_time 
FROM `uc_posts` p left join 
(
//Code entered here
SELECT * FROM uc_redwables AS T1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `dwable` , MAX(time) AS time FROM uc_redwables WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5' AND find_in_set(followed, redwabledby) > 0) OR find_in_set('5',`redwabledby`)
GROUP BY `dwable`
) AS T2
ON T1.dwable = T2.dwable AND T1.time = T2.time
ORDER by T2.time desc LIMIT 20
//Code entered ends here
) r on p.id = r.dwable
WHERE p.`postinguser` = '5' OR find_in_set('5',p.`redwabled`) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_users` WHERE `id` = '5' AND find_in_set(postinguser, following) > 0) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5' AND find_in_set(followed, redwabled) > 0) 
order by date_time desc LIMIT 20
```

I get a `Duplicate column name 'dwable'` error.

I would assume this is because it's used elsewhere. I have looked up a number of different solutions including using aliases but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: @Forbs sorry removed the tag.

Comment: You don't need to use ` around column names unless they're reserved words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is very difficult to read and I don't think you know how to use `CASE` or `FIND_IN_SET` very well, but I think I understand whats wrong.
When you're running the piece of code that works, you're returning a result set with 2 columns called `dwable` - one from `T1` and one from `T2` - which is fine until you then turn it into a derived table when you `left join` it, because a table's column names have to be unique. Basically if nothing else, change:

```
//Code entered here
SELECT * FROM uc_redwables AS T1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `dwable` , MAX(time) AS time FROM uc_redwables WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5' AND find_in_set(followed, redwabledby) > 0) OR find_in_set('5',`redwabledby`)
GROUP BY `dwable`
) AS T2 ON T1.dwable = T2.dwable AND T1.time = T2.time
ORDER by T2.time desc LIMIT 20
//Code entered ends here
```

To:

```
//Code entered here
SELECT * FROM uc_redwables AS T1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `dwable` as dwable_2 , MAX(time) AS time FROM uc_redwables WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `uc_following` WHERE `userid` = '5' AND find_in_set(followed, redwabledby) > 0) OR find_in_set('5',`redwabledby`)
GROUP BY dwable_2
) AS T2 ON T1.dwable = T2.dwable_2 AND T1.time = T2.time
ORDER by T2.time desc LIMIT 20
//Code entered ends here
```

This *should* work.